# Comparing 2 source codes with same logic

Tags: c++, algorithm, compare

This is my code for "Life, the Universe, and Everything" at hackerearth

Why "my solution" is slower than the "best solution" even though the logic
used is same!

In fact I think my logic should be faster because I printed the answer when `n!=42` but the "best solution" has to first check for `n==42` and then insert element in array (executing the 'else' part).

Please tell me why "best solution" is faster.

```
my solution :-

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;
  while(1)
  {
     scanf("%d",&n);
     if(n!=42)
     {
        printf("%d\n",n);
     }
     else
        break;
  }
  return 0;
}
Time Taken: 1.010669 seconds
---------------------------------------------------------
best solution:-
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n,a[10001],i=0,j;
  while(1)
  {
    cin>>n;
    if(n==42)
    break;
    else
    a[i++]=n;
  }
  for(j=0;j<i;j++)
  cout<<a[j]<<endl;
  return 0;
}
Time Taken: 1.004222 seconds
```

Comment: It might be something to do with the (implementation-specific) rules for when stdout is flushed

Comment: 1. what is the input? 2. can you post the code that do your measurements?

Comment: hackerearth hosts programming contests (website) and does not disclose how it measures our code. Here is a sample output for more information please visit hackerearth website  :-                                  782
796
272
344
108
168
847
268
973
95
429
797
687
689
209
603
410
385
770
481
934
742
926
911
875
690
273
102
955
505
271
553
435

Answer (score 0):

scanf and printf are extremely expensive functions in terms of processing.  They have to interpret the format string (where you write "%d" there could be a huge variety of complex format placeholders).  By the time this alone is done, the other solution has probably done it's processing already.  The source code for the scanf function would be several hundred lines of code, and printf too.

On the other hand, in the best solution the compiler knows the expected types already and has to deal with a lot less computing that is done at run time, so the conversion from input string to integer and vice versa is far more effective.

Comment: Hey Earlier I used cin & cout for input and output but the time taken was still nearly the same with printf and scanf. In fact I observed that printf and scanf was faster

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested it yet, but your output include twice as much output to console.

for  each number "best solution" prints, you add a `\n` too.
more characters = more time to process your stdout buffer.

Comment: I also did it using cout in fact printf is faster !